# \tableofcontents and \listoffigures -- suppress header after first page

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

I have set the top and bottom margins of a book class document like this:

```
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.5in}
\setlength{\footskip}{.5in}
```

and now the header of the \tableofcontents and \listoffigures clashes with (i.e. is printed over) the top line of text. I need to either suppress the headers for these pages (which are currently *CONTENTS* and *LIST* _OF_ *FIGURES*), or move them up the page a little bit. How is this done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify the page style, set `\pagestyle{empty}` before `\tableofcontents`, perhaps additionally for the first page if needed

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

or

```
\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}}
```

in the preamble, or use plain.

Or use `\markboth` to clear the headings:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\markboth{}{}}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\markboth{}{}}
```